# Angular ng-href link not working in my dev server

Tags: angularjs-ng-href

In my application in local I am using
     [{{abc}}](/#/view/%7B%7Babc%7D%7D)
In local it gets redirected to http://localhost:456/#/view/56
And in Dev link it should be redirected to
    https://www.dev.appname/projectname/#/view/56
but it gets redirected to ...//www.dev.appname/#/view/56

How can I resolve this path issue when I am in dev server??

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution to this question. By adding .. at the beginning of the URL it is working. "../#/view/{{abc}}". If we add .. in this way at the beginning the URL path is working in both local and dev servers.